# PHP - Best strategy to remove a portion of a String

Tags: php, string-formatting

I need to remove portions of a String, some examples of Strings:

```
$string1 = 'Castanho / Brown';
$string2 = 'Cor de Rosa / Pink';
```

I need to remove the content of the string after the "/", like this:

```
$newString1 = 'Castanho';
$newString2 = 'Cor de Rosa';
```

How can I in PHP do this. Some clues needed.

Best Regards,

Comment: You should be a bit more explicit about the types of input. Are they always going to have the / in there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want something that's unreadable you could do:

```
reset(explode(' / ', $input));
```

It would be sad if there wasn't a slash in the string though.

Comment: well if you really know php it's obvious what's going on but since they're asking how to split strings i don't think that's a problem they'd have.

Comment: explode() returns an array and we want a string.
PHP doesn't lets us do explode('/', $in)[0] so we use [reset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php) to extract the first element of the array.

Comment: Now, with PHP5.4, you can. http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/php-5-4-is-here-what-you-must-know/

Answer (score 2):

Regular expressions are probably the most straightforward. You'd check for a slash, and then any character at all. Something like...

```
$newString1 = preg_replace('~ / .*$~', '', $string1);
```

Answer (score 0):

use [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function :

```
$separator = " / ";
$limit = 1;
$oldString = 'Castanho / Brown';
// in case the oldString does not contain any separator it will return the oldString
$newString = explode($separator,$oldString,$limit)[0] or $oldString;
```

Comment: using a backslash as seperator when the string only contains a slash might be a typo... ;)

Comment: explode will return an array. you'd need something else to get the string out of it.

to quote the docs: "If limit is set and positive, the returned array will contain a maximum of limit elements with the last element containing the rest of string."

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex with lookahead asserts or old good strpos.

```
$string1 = 'Castanho / Brown';
$cutted = trim(substr($string1, 0, strpos($string1, '/')));
```

// note, this won't check if strpos === false so false will be evaluated to 0 and you'll get nothing :D

Answer (score 0):

You could use explode(...) (see http://php.net/manual/de/function.explode.php)

```
array explode ( string $delimiter , string $string [, int $limit ] )
```

to split your string like this

```
$string = 'Castanho / Brown';
$array = exlode(' / ', $string);

echo $array[0];
```

This is a fast solution if you alway want to cut the string after the first occurence of ' / '.

Answer (score 0):

- **$string1 = preg_replace('/\/\s+\w+/','',$string1);**

or

- . **$string= substr($string, 0,
  strpos($string, "/"));**

Answer (score 0):

The only correct way to do this:

```
$newString1 = strstr('Castanho / Brown', '/', true);
```